# VBA Code for Dynamic VLookup Between Two Open Spreadsheets from MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, automation, vba, ms-access-2010

I've taken a different approach to a work project and I'm running into a wall.  I've Google'd everything that I can think to Google and searched multiple forums before coming back to S.O. to ask for more help.  I have a form in Access that let's users enter a customer/division combination, checks to make sure that there is an existing file path for that customer, then opens excel template files and saves them to the correct folder with a customer specific file name.  This all seems to be working fine.  Here's the part that has me completely stumped.  The next part of this would be to open two of the excel files assigning, the Workbooks as variables xlWB1 and xlWB2 and the  Worksheets as xlWS1 and xlWS2(Sheet1).  I need to start in xlWB1.xlWS1.(cell D2) and do a VLookup on the value (item number) of that cell against the values of the cells in the range xlWB2.xlWS2.Range(D2:D1937).  My hope was to count the total number of rows in each worksheet before starting the VLookup so that I could assign that value to a variable and use that variable to define the bottom of the range.  I'm going to apologize in advance if the answer to this is something simple.  I've never tried to perform any operations in Excel from Access using VBA, so I'm also struggling with the syntax.  Please let me know if my question isn't clear or if there is any additional information that you need.  I've pasted my starting code below.

UPDATED CODE IN CASE ANYONE ELSE NEEDS TO USE IT!  THANK YOU ALL FOR THE HELP!!

```
Sub modExcel_SixMonth()

    Const WB_PATH As String = "\\FMI-FS\Users\sharp-c\Desktop\TestDir\"

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
    Dim rCount As Long

    Dim xlWB2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rCount2 As Long
    Dim sFormula As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim xlSheetName As String
    Dim bolIsExcelRunning As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Else
        bolIsExcelRunning = True
    End If

    xlApp.Visible = False

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH & "acct 900860 Kentucky RSTS.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets(1)

    Set xlWB2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH & "acct 900860 six months.xlsx")
    Set xlWS2 = xlWB2.Sheets(1)

    xlSheetName = xlWS2.Name

    ' rCount: RSTS Row Count
    rCount = xlWS.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Debug.Print "rCount : " & rCount

    ' rCount2: 6 Months Row Count
    rCount2 = xlWS2.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Debug.Print "rCount2 : " & rCount2

    xlWS.Activate

    With xlWS
        For i = 2 To rCount

            sFormula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & i & ", '" & WB_PATH & "[" & "acct 900860 six months.xlsx" & "]" & _
                       xlSheetName & "'!$D$2:$D$" & rCount2 & ", 1, 0)"

            Debug.Print sFormula
            .Range("D" & i).Formula = sFormula
            DoEvents
        Next
    End With

    xlWB.Save

    xlWB2.Close False                       'Closes WB Without Saving Changes
    Set xlWB2 = Nothing

    Set xlWS = Nothing
    xlWB.Close
    Set xlWB = Nothing

    If Not bolIsExcelRunning Then
    xlApp.Quit
    End If

    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: While I don't have edit privileges (I tried, this is how I found out), might I recommend you put some line breaks in the question to make it (a lot) easier to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is maybe closer to what you need.  Only need a single instance of excel for both workbooks...

```
Sub modExcel_SixMonth()

Const WB_PATH As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Chris\Desktop\TestDir\"

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
Dim rCount As Long

Dim xlWB2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRng2 As Excel.Range
Dim rCount2 As Long
Dim sFormula As String

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH & "acct 900860 Kentucky RSTS.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets(1)

    Set xlWB2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH & "acct 900860 six months.xlsx")
    Set xlWS2 = xlWB2.Sheets(1)

    ' rCount: RSTS Row Count
    rCount = xlWS.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
    Debug.Print "rCount : " & rCount

    ' rCount2: 6 Months Row Count
    rCount2 = xlWS2.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
    Debug.Print "rCount2 : " & rCount2

    sFormula = "=VLOOKUP(C2," & xlWS2.Range("D2:D1937").Address(True, True, , True) & _
                ",1,FALSE)"

   Debug.Print sFormula
   With xlWS
       .Range("D2").Formula = sFormula
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Again, I appreciate the help!  That is exactly what I needed.  Now I need to look into the arguments for the Vlookup so I can actually understand why it works!!  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the same application object? I believe this was a comment on this question earlier.

Additionally, if this doesn't work, you could use the find method of the range object. I.e.

```
XLWB2.Range("Your range here").find(XLWB1.Range( _
    "Cell containing value you're looking for").Value,lookat:=xlwhole)
```